Statistical Inquiry. Overdispersion issue or abundance of 0s
Trying to go over some data and its half presence absence while the other half is count data. The model I've been working on lately is a mix of lmer and glmer.nb as that seems to be the approach for count data. Below is the summary of an SEM i was working on yet its all lmer but I want the part of it where corresponding to F to be glmer.nm or perhaps I should use glmmTMB? does the whole thing just have to be glmer.nb or glmmTMB? Theres two other variables I want to add into the model that are count data yet if I do I get a lot of warnings or errors due to overdispersion. . . There is a warning of a predictor variable for scaling yet if I scale it, it makes a few negative values which I cant use and may be a result of 0s in the dataset. It would appear the goodness of it for chi squared and fishers is good for this current one yet I want to try to add 2 more things into it(And I know that the F is count data and should probably be in the model differently). Is that a bit too much? Suggestions?
df <- psem(
lmer(B ~  N + A + F + (1 | site), data = d8),
#lmer(A ~ F + (1 | site), data = d8),
lmer(A ~  F +(1 | site), data = d8),
lmer(T ~  F + A +   (1|site), data = d8),
lmer(S ~  B + F  + (1|site), data = d8),
lmer(D ~ A + T + (1|site),data = d8),
lmer(A ~ N + (1|site), data = d8),
lmer(C ~ F + T + S + (1|site), data = d8)
)
Structural Equation Model of df
Call:
B ~ N + A + F
A ~ F
T ~ F + A
S ~ B + A
D ~ F + T
F ~ N
C ~ A + T + S
AIC

1852.841

Tests of directed separation:
              Independ.Claim Test.Type      DF Crit.Value P.Value  
         T ~ N + ...      coef 42.0055     0.1793  0.6741  
        S ~ N + ...      coef 37.8295     1.5885  0.2153  
        D ~ N + ...      coef 55.9602     1.1410  0.2900  
     C ~ N + ...      coef 31.7632     1.5056  0.2288  
          A ~ N + ...      coef 46.8297     2.6263  0.1118  
  T ~ B + ...      coef 28.2731     0.5232  0.4754  
 D ~ B + ...      coef 35.3531     0.0203  0.8875  

C ~ B + ...      coef 29.7178     0.9221  0.3447
S ~ T + ...      coef 46.8141     1.5520  0.2190
D ~ S + ...      coef 54.9386     0.3143  0.5773
A ~ S + ...      coef 55.9466     5.2821  0.0253 *
C ~ D + ...      coef 33.4871     0.0050  0.9442
A ~ D + ...      coef 48.2623     0.3947  0.5328
A ~ C + ...      coef 52.9124     0.0062  0.9375
--
Global goodness-of-fit:
Chi-Squared = 11.829 with P-value = 0.893 and on 19 degrees of freedom
Fisher's C = 30.515 with P-value = 0.339 and on 28 degrees of freedom

Coefficients:
 Response   Predictor  Estimate Std.Error      DF Crit.Value P.Value Std.Estimate    
   B        N         9.7176    1.0037 46.0216    91.5297  0.0000       0.9343 ***
   B        A       -0.1836    0.0421 43.7463    18.7062  0.0001      -0.3859 ***
   B        F       0.0020    0.0005 41.9443    16.0755  0.0002       0.3260 ***
   A        F        0.0060    0.0013 53.6423    21.5820  0.0000       0.4709 ***
   T        F      -0.0018    0.0006 56.5517     8.6751  0.0047      -0.4254  **
   T        A     0.1209    0.0506 48.7150     5.2512  0.0263       0.3557   *
   S        B     0.1892    0.0449 55.4474    16.8407  0.0001       0.4623 ***
   S        F      -0.0009    0.0002 50.4275    14.3701  0.0004      -0.3607 ***
   D        F    0.0007    0.0003 50.4177     6.9658  0.0110       0.2295   *
   D        T    0.2084    0.0660 51.4101     9.5847  0.0032       0.2801  **
   F        N   -701.2503  250.3729 49.6386     7.1996  0.0099      -0.4094  **
   C        A    0.0007    0.0006 48.6534     1.2172  0.2753       0.1311    
   C        T    0.6899    0.1468 50.4268    20.1428  0.0000       0.5521 ***
   C        S   -0.5645    0.2596 40.3871     4.3953  0.0423      -0.2589   *

Signif. codes:  0 '' 0.001 '' 0.01 '' 0.05

Individual R-squared:
 Response method Marginal Conditional
   B      none     0.30        0.95
   B      none     0.22        0.66
   T      none     0.15        0.40
   S      none     0.24        0.77
   D      none     0.13        0.76
   A      none     0.14        0.51
   C      none     0.32        0.49


Welcome to the site. Can you summarize the main questions you are asking, perhaps as a list at the beginning or end of your Q as it’s a bit hard to follow as is
